# Custom Loss Function backpropagation

Tags: pytorch, gradient, backpropagation, pre-trained-model

I have difficulties telling my Neural Network to compute the gradients defined by a pretrained model of SpeechBrain. I have created a little toy example demonstrating this (the toy example doesn't make sense). When executing it, you will see that the loss doesn't change over the epochs. The reason is that I don't backpropagate through the network, i.e. weights are not adapted.

Important to understand: I use the pretrained model *f* of SpeechBrain as part of my loss function. I don't want to backpropagate through it. I just want to know the gradients
*df(x)/dxi*.

```
import torch.nn as nn
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule
from speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderClassifier
import torch.nn as nnloss

from torch import optim

from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import os
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import pytorch_lightning as pl


class LightningMNISTClassifier(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    # mnist images are (1, 28, 28) (channels, width, height)
    self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128)
    self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(128, 256)
    self.layer_3 = nn.Linear(256, 10)

  def forward(self, x):
      batch_size, channels, width, height = x.size()

      # (b, 1, 28, 28) -> (b, 1*28*28)
      x = x.view(batch_size, -1)

      # layer 1 (b, 1*28*28) -> (b, 128)
      x = self.layer_1(x)


      # layer 2 (b, 128) -> (b, 256)
      x = self.layer_2(x)


      # layer 3 (b, 256) -> (b, 10)
      x = self.layer_3(x)



      return x

  def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):
    return F.nll_loss(logits, labels)

  def customLoss(self, logits, target):
      transformed_logits = w2v.encode_batch(logits.flatten()).to('cuda').requires_grad_(True)
      transformed_target = w2v.encode_batch(target.flatten()).to('cuda')
      loss = mse(transformed_logits, transformed_target)
      return loss

  def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
      x, y = train_batch
      logits = self.forward(x)
      loss = self.customLoss(logits, x)
      self.log('train_loss', loss)
      return loss

  def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx):
      x, y = val_batch
      logits = self.forward(x)
      loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, y)
      self.log('val_loss', loss)

  def configure_optimizers(self):
      optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
      return optimizer





if __name__=='__main__':
    # data
    # transforms for images
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

    # prepare transforms standard to MNIST
    mnist_train = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    mnist_test = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size=64)
    val_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=64)

    # functions for custom loss functions
    w2v = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source='speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb')  # this is by default on the cpu
    mse = nnloss.MSELoss()

    # train
    model = LightningMNISTClassifier()
    trainer = pl.Trainer()

    trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader, val_loader)
```

If check on *transformed_logits* in *custom loss*, then you will see that it has no grad_fn, i.e. there is computations of the gradients w.r.t to the pretrained w2v model.

Comment: Is `w2v.encode_batch` differentiable?

Comment: I don't think it is. But since ```w2v = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source='speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb')  ``` loads a .cpkt file there should be a way to load the net as a differentiable function?

Comment: Loading is one thing, but the fact that it is not differentiable means you cannot propagate gradient from the output to its input. This is probably the reason why it fails here.

Comment: w2v is a neural network. It is just pretrained, i.e.the weights are loaded from somewhere. Neural networks are all differentiable (otherwise you couldn't train them), so there must be a way to load the checkpoint file in such a way that I could continue the training. Im just don't know it how to do it with the SpeechBrain classes....

Comment: You should look at fixing the gradient flow first and look into loading the model after. In your `customLoss` function, can you tell us if `w2v.encode_batch(logits.flatten())` has a `grad_fn` attribute?

Comment: I resolve this problem, it's a bug from SpeechBrain. You cant input batchsize=1 as input...